# Суммирование по условиям. Ошибка в формуле

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Нужно найти ошибку в формуле.

Описание что мне нужно:

`'Заказы(03)'!C:C` - тут нужно просуммировать, если выполняются условия
`'Заказы(03)'!A:A;"="&A3&""` - Это дата
`'Заказы(03)'!D2` - это имя сотрудника
`"=&B2&""` - опять таки имя сотрудника

```
=SUMIFS('Заказы(03)'!C:C;'Заказы(03)'!A:A;"="&A3&"";'Заказы(03)'!D2;"=&B2&"");0)"))
```

Если я убираю `'Заказы(03)'!D2;"=&B2&""`, то будет все считаться, а мне нужно, чтобы считало определенного сотрудника в эту ячейку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сравните выражения в кавычках:
`"="&A3&""`
и 
`"=&B2&"");0)"`

Во втором случае явно ошибка. Вероятно, должно быть 
`"="&B2);0)`

Да и в первом случае в `&""` нет никакого смысла, можно оставить `"="&A3`

---

UPDATE 1.

1. В критериях проверки можно вообще опустить знак равенства.
2. У вас ошибка в диапазоне для проверки имени сотрудника: вместо `Заказа(03)!D2` должно быть `Заказа(03)!D:D` - диапазон, в котором указыны имена.
   Итого, формула приобретает следующий вид:

   =SUMIFS('Заказы(03)'!C:C;'Заказы(03)'!A:A;A3;'Заказы(03)'!D:D;B2)

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c626524/v626524829/55d0b/GCGKlqfr4FI.jpg
https://pp.userapi.com/c626524/v626524829/55d14/lhoSiCszIZk.jpg

Не получается у меня всё равно.

Comment: Обновил решение.

Comment: Получилось. Понял свою ошибку. Спасибо большое.